# Tiles not displaying in ArcGIS Online at furthest zoom level

Tags: arcgis-online, tiles, arcgis-online-basemaps

In an application I am "building" in ArcGIS Online (not server), our starting view is a global level. The issue is that Zoom Level #3 (example) cuts off part of our dataset in the extremes--alaska and the pacific. Zoom level #2 causes the edges of the map to turn null-colored (pic 1), even though the tiles appear to be loading in the cache (pic 2).

[image]

*Grey bars on side*

[image]

*Tiles appear to load but are not seen*

Is there a way to address this null space in ArcGIS Online?

---

**I made a posting on [geonet.esri.com](https://geonet.esri.com/ideas/13315-disable-map-frame-clipping-at-max-extent-arcgis-online). Hopefully it gets some attention.**

Comment: Wild guess based on your last screen shot - something to do with wrap around? https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jssamples/map_wraparound.html

Comment: @KHibma I thought that at first, so I tested my theory by adding a polygon to the map. I then edited and stretched the polygon to exceed the extent of the basemap. AGOL would allow me to stretch the polygon beyond 90 degrees N and S, but would not allow me to pull it beyond the E W extent (and into the grey abyss). It seems the issue is with the frame containing the map, not the map itself.

Comment: Hmm, looking at any apps I have, when I zoom out to max, it gives the 'nothing' on the sides. I sort of suspect thats just how it is. I can't say that with authority though. If you haven't, it might be worth posting on the JS-geonet forum

Comment: @KHibma , Done! https://geonet.esri.com/ideas/13315-disable-map-frame-clipping-at-max-extent-arcgis-online

Comment: I can see that you have submitted an ArcGIS Idea for this so I think you should remove the update from your question and write an answer that links to and describes your ArcGIS Idea briefly.